# Regress on matrix on vector to obtain rank-one approximation in Partial Least Square

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, least-squares

I'm trying to understand the equation for partial least squares (PLS) regression from the paper "A survey of partial least squares (PLS) methods, with emphasis on the two-blocks case". I'm having trouble understanding how the equation is derived based on the paper. Can someone please explain it to me?
Here is a more detailed explanation of the question:

The equation for PLS regression is given in the paper as follows:

$$
\hat{X}_1(\epsilon_1) = \epsilon_1((\epsilon_1^T \epsilon_1)^{-1} \epsilon_1^T X_1)
$$

This paper tell me that we want to regress

Comment: Your really haven't given enough context. What is $X_1$? What is $\epsilon_1$? Are these matrices, vectors? What are their sizes?

Comment: That said, the equation looks like a simple application of linear least squares. If $X_1$ is a vector, then $\hat v = (\epsilon_1^T\epsilon_1)^{-1} \epsilon_1^T X_1$ is the least-squares solution to the equation $\epsilon_1 v = X_1$, and $\epsilon_1 \hat v$ is the corresponding estimate of $X_1$.